# How to create multiple directories with incrementing numbers in a single command?

Tags: bash, debian, command-line

I'd like to simplify this command:

```
mkdir -p {fg0,fg1,fg2,fg3,fg4,fg5,fg6,fg7,fg8,fg9,fg10,fg11,fg12,fg13,fg14}
```

The goal is to create an *n* number of folders where the numbers increment. I could potentially have 100's of folders, and find it unpractical to add each one individually.

Any thoughts on how to simplify this with a single command?

Comment: assuming bash, mkdir -p fg{0..14}

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That did it. Appreciate it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming bash, you can create text sequences using the abbreviation {i..n}

So, I advise doing for having the directories balanced, per @cas sugestion:

```
mkdir -p fg{00..14}
```

It will create fg00 ... f01 with newer bash versions 4.x balancing and ordering better the names, and fg0, fg1...with older bash versions (3.x).

If fg0...fg14 is still a requirement, as per your example, than it is indeed:

```
mkdir -p fg{0..14}
```

Comment: Again, appreciate it. Will accept soon as timer runs out

Comment: or use `fg{00.14}` - the leading zero causes the output to be zero-padded to the same length.  the directory names will sort naturally.

Comment: @cas it is not doing that.
$ echo fg{00..14}
fg0 fg1 fg2 fg3 fg4 fg5 fg6 fg7 fg8 fg9 fg10 fg11 fg12 fg13 fg14

Comment: works with bash  4.4.12(1)-release.  `echo {00..14}` prints `fg00 fg01 fg02 fg03 fg04 fg05 fg06 fg07 fg08 fg09 fg10 fg11 fg12 fg13 fg14`.   which is nice, i remember it not doing that in the past, and having to use `seq` instead.

Comment: @cas OSX with  3.2.57....changing the answer. it works both ways.

Comment: Or, in both versions of bash: `mkdir $(printf 'fg%02d' {0..14})` (assuming default IFS).

Answer (score 1):

Something inspired from that I think is good method

```
mkdir $(seq --format 'fg%.0f' 1 100)
```